# Stopping mightySlider grid view to position slides randomly

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using grid view of mightySlider. It's working fine but I don't want my slides position to be set randomly.I want  a fix position of my slides.

This is the code I'm using :

```
            function getViewport() {
            var e = window,
                a = 'inner';
            if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
                a = 'client';
                e = document.documentElement || document.body;
            }
            return {
                width: e[a + 'Width'],
                height: e[a + 'Height']
            }
        }


        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var $win = $(window),
                isTouch = !!('ontouchstart' in window),
                clickEvent = isTouch ? 'tap' : 'click',
                $gridsContainer = $('ul.items'),
                $big = $('li.bigGrid', $gridsContainer),
                $wide = $('li.wideGrid', $gridsContainer),
                $large = $('li.largeGrid', $gridsContainer),
                $small = $('li.smallGrid', $gridsContainer),
                $frames = $('.frame', $gridsContainer),
                sliders = $frames.length,
                history = [],
                wall = new freewall('ul.items');

            function resizeGrids(width) {
                var bigWidth = $big.eq(0).outerWidth(),
                    wideWidth = $wide.eq(0).outerWidth(),
                    largeWidth = $large.eq(0).outerWidth(),
                    smallWidth = $small.eq(0).outerWidth();

                if (width <= 480) {
                    $big.height(bigWidth);
                    $small.height(smallWidth);
                    $wide.height(wideWidth);
                    $large.height(largeWidth);
                }
                else {
                    $big.height(bigWidth);
                    $small.height(smallWidth);
                    $wide.height(wideWidth / 2);
                    $large.height(largeWidth * 2);
                }

                wall.fitWidth();
            }


            wall.reset({
                selector: 'li',
                animate: 0,
                cellW: 300,
                cellH: 300,
                fixSize: 0,
                gutterY: 0,
                gutterX: 0,
                onResize: function () {
                    wall.fitWidth();
                }
            });


            function countDown(sliderID) {
                var time = 5000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

                history[sliderID] = clearTimeout(history[sliderID]);

                history[sliderID] = setTimeout(function() {
                    var api = $frames.eq(sliderID).data('mightySlider');

                    if(api.relative.activeSlide === api.slides.length - 1)
                        api.activate(0);
                    else
                        api.next();
                }, time);
            }


            // Resize the grids height to fix the aspect ratio
            resizeGrids(getViewport().width);


            $.fn.randomize = function(selector){
                var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
                    $parents = $elems.parent();

                $parents.each(function(){
                    $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
                        return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
                    }).detach().appendTo(this);
                });

                return this;
            };


            $gridsContainer.randomize();


            $frames.mightySlider({
                speed: 1000,
                viewport: 'fill',
                easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                startRandom:  0,  
                // Navigation options
                navigation: {
                    slideSize: '100%'
                },

                // Dragging options
                dragging: {
                    mouseDragging: 0,
                    touchDragging: 0
                }
            }, {
                active: function() {
                    var sliderID = $frames.index(this.frame);
                    countDown(sliderID);
                }
            });


            $win.on('resize', function() {
                // Resize the grids height to fix the aspect ratio
                resizeGrids(getViewport().width);
            });

            setTimeout(function(){
                $win.trigger('resize');
            }, 100);
        });
```

How Can I fix my slides positions??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you remove or comment out the `$gridsContainer.randomize();` portion of your code, it will not call the `randomize` function and will stop randomizing the slides for you.